# How to properly save from belongs_to to has_one relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, belongs-to, has-one

I have a rails application with two seperate models with two separate views called Office and Prospect.

Office Model:

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :prospect
end
```

Prospect Model:

```
class Prospect < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office

  def office_company
    office.try(:company)
  end

  def office_date
    office.try(:office_date)
  end

  def office_company=(company)
    self.office = Office.find_or_create_by(company: company)
  end

  def office_date=(office_date)
    self.office = Office.find_or_create_by(office_date: office_date)
  end
end
```

The Prospect table has an office_id key.

Prospect Form View:

```
  <!-- Date -->
  <div class="row form-box-outline">
    <div class="form-subheader">Date</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Office_Date %>
      <%= f.text_field :office_date, class: "space form-control input-width",
                       'data-provide' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                       'data-date-today-highlight' => 'true', 'data-date-orientation' => 'bottom auto',
                       'data-date-today-btn' => 'linked', 'data-date-autoclose' => 'true',
                       'data-date-keyboard-navigation' => 'false' %>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Prospect Information -->
  <div class="row form-box-outline">
    <div class="form-subheader subform-box-outline">Prospect Information</div>
    <div class="subform-box-outline">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <%= f.label :Company, "Account Prospect" %>
        <%= f.text_field :office_company, class: 'space form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When creating a new Prospect, I need access to the company field and and the date field (and in the future, probably one or two more fields) on the Office model, which is no problem with defined methods I've written. The problem shows up when I save a new Prospect, two database entries get saved in the Office model. One entry with the customer and  and one for the date. The Prospect model has one entry saved: one with the prospect info and office_id key. I believe this is happening because two objects are getting created then saved.

1. What is the best way to combine my methods so I'm always creating one entry per create and update in my form view?
2. Is the has_one belongs_to relationship the best way to do this? I feel some resistance that this isn't best practice or the Rails way.
3. I've already tried this with using nested attributes but found that every time a record was created, the prospect edit view was blank with company and date even though the entry existed on the Office table and office_id key was present.
4. A Prospect is a possible future Office but not active (customer) Office. An Office can be active, prospect or inactive. I want a user to easily move a Prospect to an (active) Office (this is set with a dropdown during Prospect or Office creation) and not create a Prospect with a separate company name.
5. The Prospect and Office tables contain very different information but do share a handful of fields (company, date, status, user). Office table contains all company information (company name, address, etc.). The Prospect table contains marketing stuff that pertains to that Office. I wanted Prospects to have a separate view controller and model to help distinguish it from Offices.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a select box and pass in an array of offices. It doesn't make sense to be saving a office id and displaying a company. As long as your office_id gets sent through as a param in the controller it will save the id and the relationship defined in the model will handle the active record relation.

I think this is what you are after. I would stay away from creating two records in different tables.

Comment: What I'm trying to prevent is two records getting saved in the Office table. What is happening is that the company and office_date fields get saved from Prospects as separate records in the Office table. I want one record saved that includes the company and office_date fields in the Office table.

Comment: I do see your point about using a select box instead of a field. You highlighted a separate issue with what I'm trying to do.